# Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on $(0,1]$. Find the distribution function and the density function of $Y=-\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm doing this problem and I have some doubts:

> Let $X$ be a continuous uniform random variable on $(0,1]$. Find the pdf and the density function of $Y=-\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(X)$, with $\lambda >0$.

Here's what I've done:

> We know that
>
> $$F_{X}(t)=\cases{0\ \ \  \text{if}\ \ \  t\leq 0\\t\ \ \  \text{if}\ \ \  t\in (0,1]\\1\ \ \  \text{if}\ \ \  t> 1}.$$
>
> From here, we want $F_{Y}(t)$. This is:
>
> $$F_{Y}(t)=P\{Y\leq t\}=P\{-\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(X)\leq t\}=P\{X\geq e^{-\lambda t}\}.$$

How do I see from here who is $F_{Y}(t)?$ Can I see it using the density function of $X$?

Comment: Notice that $Pr[X \leq x] = Pr[X < x] = F_X(x)$. So, you are almost done.

Comment: @Michael What does it mean? Where can I apply it?

Comment: Same way you applied the definition of $F_Y(t)$, but, in reverse.

Comment: What is blocking you from finishing your chain of equalities by writing $Pr[X \leq e^{-\lambda t}]$ in terms of $F_X(x)$?

Comment: @Michael I don't know how to define the new intervals for the distribution function, and how's the image for every point in $Y$.

Comment: What do you mean "the new intervals"? And "how's the image"?  Can you say what specifically is blocking you? Notice that $F_X(x)$ is defined for all real numbers $x$, you do not need to worry about $x$ being in certain intervals.

Comment: @Michael I need to define $F_{Y}(t)$, just like I did with $F_{X}$, and I don't know how this function is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30935/discussion-between-michael-and-abrahamlure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have \begin{align}
F_Y(t) &= \mathbb P(X\geqslant e^{-\lambda t})\\ &= 1- \mathbb P(X\leqslant e^{-\lambda t})\\
&= 1 -( e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,1]}(e^{-\lambda t}) + \mathsf 1_{[1,\infty)}(e^{-\lambda t}))\\
&= (1 - e^{-\lambda t})\mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(t),
\end{align}
so that $Y\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$. (Note that $0<e^{-\lambda t}\leqslant 1$ for $0\leqslant t<1$.)

Comment: but the cumulative distribution function has to sum one, maybe it's $(1-e^{-\lambda t})1_{[0,\infty})(t)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that typo

Comment: Hi. I know this is four years-old, but I was just curious: How did you derive the final equation from the second-to-last one? Thanks.

Comment: @Seankala $\mathsf1_{(0,1]}(e^{-\lambda t}$ means $0<e^{-\lambda t}\leqslant 1$. This is true for all $t>0$, independent of $\lambda$ (assuming $\lambda>0$, of course).